# Is there a noun/phrase to call someone living far away from their hometown?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

Let's say that Jacob is a student of a high school coming from a place 150 miles away. Because it's inefficient to commute between his school and his home, Jacob decided to rent an apartment near his school and lives there, thus Jacob is now living far away from his home.

Now suppose there is a neighbor working as a consultant, Sasha, who also lives far away from his hometown but she has been living there for 3 years. Seeing Jacob struggling because this is the first time he need to live by his own, Sasha as a fellow ________ is symphatetic to him and often gives him advices.

Is there a noun/ phrase/ short and concise words to fill in the gaps? Note that Sasha's hometown, Jacob's hometown, and the school all are in a same country.

A simple google translate gives me *migrant* and *settled foreigners*, but I feel like *migrant* have somewhat negative connotation, is more appropriate when it's used in political context and draws lot association with border immigration... Also I think *settled foreigners* is not best choice, from the school area residents point of view, they're not foreigners.

Another word that came out from my head is *fugitive*. Google, Merriam-webster, and other popular online dictionaries suggest it's used to imply someone is living far away in the context of fleeing/escaping because of fear/other reasons. However, Jacob and Sasha are not necessarily running away from their hometown.

[An answer from this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57978/is-there-a-specific-word-phrase-for-a-student-living-in-the-city-of-his-uni-coll) suggests *suitcase student*, but Sasha is not a student. Also it's somewhat uncommon to see its usage.

I'm confused. Please help.

Comment: Consider *stranger*, (a resident alien).

Comment: There may not be a brief word/phrase that describes what you want. [out-of-towner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out-of-towner) may work, especially in the student sense. If the issue is specifically bc they are far from their family members - "as someone living far from home/family" may apply too.

Comment: @LucianSava Could you please elaborate why _stranger_ works in that case?

Comment: @katatahito "as someone living far from home/family" is a bit mouthy, but I will consider _out-of-towner_, thanks. I'm still looking for other options though.

Comment: Because they aren't locals, natives of that place.

Comment: It's almost like you want a word like *exile* but without quite absolute permanence of this.

Comment: @katatahito I think your comment is the closest to a proper answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with a *slightly* metaphorical sense:

From Merriam-Webster's Learner's dictionary:

> [transplant](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/transplant) *noun*
>
> > 2 [count] : a person who has moved to a new home especially in a different region or country
> >
> > *She's a Southern transplant who now lives in New York.*

---

A location based adjective (Southern, British, Ohio, etc.) could be placed in front of transplant, or "transplant" could be followed by "from ~~".

Comment: To my ear this sounds like a deportee.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**expatriate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expatriate#h3) (or, in UK English, just [*expat*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expat)):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : a person who lives in a foreign country
>   // Hemingway himself in *The Sun Also Rises*, 1926, had given the picture of the dislocated life of young English and American *expatriates* in the bars of Paris, the "lost generation," as Gertrude Stein defined them.
>   — Robert Penn Warren

You are an *expatriate* of your native country.

In the example sentence:

> Seeing Jacob struggling because this is the first time he need to live by his own, Sasha as a fellow *expatriate* is sympathetic to him and often gives him advice.

---

Note that although the definition of the word refers to *a foreign country*, it could still be used and understood if applied to a province, state, or even city instead. Essentially, it just means that you come from somewhere different.

For example, I grew up in Toronto but no longer live there; however, I do still live in Ontario. It would be understood if I referred to myself as a *Toronto expatriate*; if I moved to a different province but stayed in Canada, I would be an *Ontario expatriate*.

Comment: From the body of the question: *Note that Sasha's hometown, Jacob's hometown, and the school all are in a same country*.

Comment: 150 miles doesn't necessarily mean another country, but this does give a sense of not being near the family home.